# Prepare STMT statement giving syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am getting syntax error running prepare stmt here. I tried executing the query in @c manually and it worked. Not sure why the stmt is giving this error.
Here's the code I'm using.

```
SET @i=24;
SET @Bill_month='2019-01-01';
SET @STARTDATE= date_sub( @Bill_month,interval @i MONTH);
SET @ENDDATE= date_sub( @Bill_month,interval @i - 1 MONTH);
SET @TABLENAME= CONCAT('BA_DEV.INVOICE',MONTH(@Bill_month),'_',@i);
SET @c := CONCAT('DROP temporary TABLE if exists tempdb.cohort_month;

             CREATE temporary TABLE if not exists tempdb.cohort_month
             select * from ba_dev.invoice_',EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM @STARTDATE),'_ongoing_STEP2;');

PREPARE stmt from @c;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE temporary TABLE if not exists tempdb.cohort_month           select * from' at line 3 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1):

You can only execute one statement execute the drop first then execute the create.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

> SET @c := CONCAT('DROP temporary TABLE if exists tempdb.cohort_month;CREATE temporary >TABLE if not exists tempdb.cohort_month;select * from ba_dev.invoice_',EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH >FROM @STARTDATE),'_ongoing_STEP2;');